# How to ignore uniquename for an specific author with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing about this author and most of my references are of her work. There's only one single entry by another person with the same lastname and I'd like that only this entry were disambiguated with the given name, as in

> [image: expected result]

I tried to manually edit the `.bbl` file and set the `uniquename` field to `0`, and that works. So I tried this:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=hash,
        match={d6cfb2b8c4b3f9440ec4642438129367},
        final]
      \step[fieldset=uniquename, fieldvalue=0]
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work (I don't think `hash` and `uniquename` are "fields", but I don't know how to call them)

Here's a non working mwe:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mainauthor,
  author = {Jane Doe},
  title = {Title},
  year = {2016},
  option = {uniquename=false},
}
@book{another,
  author = {Hans Doe},
  title = {Title},
  year = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=hash,
        match={d6cfb2b8c4b3f9440ec4642438129367},
        final]
      \step[fieldset=uniquename, fieldvalue=0]
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\autocites{mainauthor,another}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that the sourcemapping step occurs much earlier than the actual disambiguation process. So you can't overwrite `uniquename` using source mapping.

Comment: According to the documentation, though, `uniquename` should be a per-entry option, but not even that seems to work in your MWE - maybe that is a bug, or I misunderstand what should be happening in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here should imho work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretonameformat{labelname}{%
 \iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{mainauthor}{\setcounter{uniquename}{0}}{}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\autocites{mainauthor,another}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you probably have more than one entry with Jane Doe, it is as moewe remarked better to test again a hash, probably the hash field for the name Jane Doe is the best suited:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretonameformat{labelname}{%
 \iffieldequalstr{hash}{d6cfb2b8c4b3f9440ec4642438129367}{\setcounter{uniquename}{0}}{}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\autocites{mainauthor,another}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 though I would test against the hash: `\iffieldequalstr{namehash}{d6cfb2b8c4b3f9440ec4642438129367}` (or `fullhash`?) and not the `entrykey`.

Comment: @moewe: right, I forgot that J. Doe would have more than one entry.

Comment: That would be the idea, presumably.

Comment: @moewe: I edited the answer, imho hash is the best field (but the example is to mini to be sure).

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I prefer testing against the hash as @moewe suggested, it covers cases where the author's name is given by `sortauthor` as well.

Comment: Oh, yes we are in a name format and there `hash` is available after all. Then `hash` is definitely the best choice (much better than `namehash` or `fullhash`).